# PowerShell script returning node count of 0

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to count the number of operation nodes in my XML file.

```
[xml]$doc =  [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02"><Alerts />
<Operations>
<Operation Name="Alter">
<Item  />
<Item  />
<Item  />
</Operation>
</Operations>
</DeploymentReport>
'@
$info = $doc.SelectNodes("/DeploymentReport/Operations/Operation")
$info.count
```

However, `$info.count` is always returning 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$info = $doc.DeploymentReport.Operations.Operation; 
$info.ChildNodes.Count`

Answer (score 1):

You're not selecting the nodes with the correct namespace. You'd need to do something like:

```
[Xml] $Doc =  [Xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02">
    <Alerts/>
    <Operations>
        <Operation Name="Alter">
            <Item/>
            <Item/>
            <Item/>
        </Operation>
    </Operations>
</DeploymentReport>
'@

$NSM = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $Doc.NameTable
$NSM.AddNamespace("dr", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02")

$Info = $Doc.SelectNodes("/dr:DeploymentReport/dr:Operations/dr:Operation", $NSM)
$Info.Count
1
```